# Downgrade ROS from Jade to Indigo

Tags: ros

Is it possible to downgrade from ROS Jade to Indigo?

For those who are not yet familiar with Robot Operating System (ROS), here: [ROS](http://ros.org)

Comment: You can have Jade and Indigo installed on the same system and use each one individually with different projects. Do you mean downgrade in the sense of "I'm using Jade and want to switch to Indigo" or in the sense of "I have a package of software programmed using Ros Jade and I want to port the software to work with Indigo" ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have Jade on my system but it appears that in order to use turtlebot_simulator, I would need Indigo. When I did an apt-get install of turtlebot_simulator on Jade, I got an error "Unable to locate package ros-jade-turtlebot-simulator". Is there any other workaround for the issue? Also, I have a few packages which I am still working on, hence starting from scratch is not an option.

Answer (score 2):

You can have Jade and Indigo installed in parallel on the same system and use each one individually with different projects.

Ask on [answers.ros.org](http://answers.ros.org). Don't forget to tell them what OS & OS version you are using. Installing Indigo in parallel via manual installation should not present any problems. apt style installation depends on your OS & version.

Comment: All you would need after installing both of them is to load the correct `setup.sh` or something like that in your `.bashrc`.

Comment: Yes, good point. I have two bash functions in my .bashrc, 'indigo' and 'jade' that I run to prepare the shell for working with one or the other.